# Eliminate/reduce speaker pop when powering off amp

Tags: capacitor, audio, amplifier

I'm repairing an old 1970's record player and one of the items on my list is to try and reduce the loud 'pop' noise when switching off the amp. I've done a little research and it seems there are a few different reasons this might be happening, my first challenge has been diagnosing the origin of the problem.

<s>A common fault is arcing across the power switch contacts. I've seen various suggestions for this online, including:</s>

- Add an X2 cap across the power switch
- Add an X2 cap across the power transformer primary
- Add an MOV (in series?) with the transformer primary
- Replace the switch

I've ruled out (with some help in the comments) that the problem is not likely to be the power switch contacts. I've now identified the following conditions cause the pop:

- Turning the amp off with the power switch
- Pulling the plug on the amp while it is switched on
- Stopping the turntable (the amp and turntable deck are one unit)

The last condition is particularly interesting, since the amp does not lose power when the turntable stops. My next step is to familiarise myself with the link between the deck and the amp, as this might narrow down the source of the problem.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here. Is there a better approach to my problem that I should be taking?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a DC offset across the speaker itself?

Comment: If you kill the power by pulling out the plug from the mains do you get the pop? If so it isn't the switch.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Good point, I'm not sure. The PCB is very untidy and I'm not familiar with some of the old components it contains. I'll try to isolate the area driving the speaker and perhaps post up a couple of photos...

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Thanks for your suggestions, I've updated my question with my findings and agree it's unlikely to be the switch after all.

Comment: Have you been lucky enough to find a service manual for the thing?

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is a service manual for the [CC10 turntable](http://www.vinylengine.com/library/garrard/cc10.shtml), but the amp has no brand or model number and my search to track either down has been fruitless so far.